# Rails Convert Time String to Spoken Text String

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datetime-format

In Ruby/Rails, is there a built-in method or gem to convert a date string

```
"Friday February 7, 3:30AM 2014"
```

to

```
"Friday February seventh, three thirty AM two thousand fourteen"`
```

I wanted to see if anyone had a solution before I tried to roll my own.

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/humanize converts numbers to plain english, but doesn't handle ordinals.  I ended up writing my own methods, but hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method or gem. You need to create your own.